# Custom 'Edit Profile' Location in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What I am trying to do is have the Edit Profile option in the Admin bar at the top of a wordpress page go to another url.

Basically instead of it going to the /wp-admin directory

I am trying to get it to go the the /editprofile.php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter [`edit_profile_url`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_profile_url):

```
add_filter( 'edit_profile_url', 'custom_profile_link_so_19216787', 10, 3 );

function custom_profile_link_so_19216787( $url, $user, $scheme )
{
    return site_url( 'editprofile' );
}
```

I suppose that `/editprofile.php` is a page using this template and that its address is `example.com/editprofile`. If that's not the case, put a full URL instead of `site_url($slug)`.

<sub>*Related: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much that actually did exactly what I wanted it to do.